# How to Post a List<class> in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, list

In java, I can easily convert a list of classes into a jsonbody like this.

```
 jsonBody = new JSONArray(new Gson().toJson(eventFeeList));
```

However, in swift, many answers that I have seen say that I need to convert my jsonbody into an array[string:any].

Do I need to convert to [string:any]? And if so, how do I do that if I want this desired jsonbody?

My Desired json body:

```
 [
   {
     "key1" = "value1"
     "key2" = "value2"
     "key3" = "value3"
   },
   {
     "key1" = "value1"
     "key2" = "value2"
     "key3" = "value3"
   }
 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

With SwiftyJSON you could do something like this:

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let valueKey1 = json[0]["key1"].string {
  //Now you got your value
  print(valueKey1)
}
```

Of course, you should create an object and fill his properties then add these object in a list.

See the the example:

```
// USE SwiftyJSON to parse data
let json = JSON(data)

// Get Objects
let jsonArr:[JSON] = json.array!

for objectJSON in jsonArr {

    // Parse Object
    let exampleObject = ExampleObject(jsonOBject: objectJSON)
    listObjects.append(exampleObject)

}
```

And the init for the "ExampleObject" would be:

```
init(jsonOBject: JSON) {

    name = ""
    title = ""

    if let nameObject = jsonOBject["name"].string {
        self.name = nameObject
    }

    if let titleObject = jsonOBject["title"].string {
        self.title = titleObject
    }


}
```